# Android Animation : View directly change to end position

Tags: android, animation, android-studio, objectanimator

I get an assignment to create a game like candy crush saga and flow for android platform. I've try some tutorial about event listener and animation, it work well but I got problem when I animate ImageView to change its position.
I want to make change position between two ImageView when I swipe on of ImageView (candy crush gameplay), it was changed position perfectly but the problem is the animation movement is not working. When I swipe one of the ImageView (Right swipe for example), that ImageView changed position with ImageView which located beside it but I don't see movement animation like when I play candy crush saga. 
I use 2 ObjectAnimator to animate that ImageView and play it together when Swipe Event was trigger on that ImageView. this is my animation code.

```
final String name = "x";
ImageView target = (ImageView) findViewById(id[x-1][y-1]);
ImageView next = (ImageView) findViewById(id[x-1][y]);
ObjectAnimator aTarget = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, name, target.getX(), (target.getX()+target.getWidth()));
   aTarget.setDuration(1000);
   aTarget.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
ObjectAnimator aNext = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(next, name, next.getX(), (next.getX()-next.getWidth()));
   aNext.setDuration(1000);
   aNext.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
AnimatorSet moveset = new AnimatorSet();
moveset.playTogether(aTarget, aNext);
moveset.start();
```

I use ID array to save my ImageView's ID and I using 'for' to compare View's ID which trigger swipe event with list ID inside ID array so I can find where ImageView which choosen to be moved (target) and other ImageView which will changed position with choosen one.
I don't understand what wrong with that code, I get that code from animation tutorial source code from 
http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/a-property-animation-tutorial.html
It works perfectly when I run the application but when I try to implement it to my application I got this problem. 
Hope somebody can help me, Thanks so much before.

Comment: The code above works perfectly for me. Could be something with the project setup or your device or something else in the code.

Comment: ty so much for your information, it finally works..
I'm sorry, this problem is my own fault..
The problem came from phone;s developer setting, I forget to setting animation so I set to off..
for other people who get problem like me you should check your developer setting too, maybe you also get prolem like me
thanks